# Magento:exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail

Tags: php, magento, zend-mail

### Magento 1.7, Qmail as smtp, Parallel plesk 10.3, Centos

Since a few days one of my magento installation is not sending email, the problem affect only one magento installation.

the excepTion log report:

```
2013-10-14T15:05:41+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in /var/www/vhosts/domain.ext/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137
 Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ext/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ext/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
 #2 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ext/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(454): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ext/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(506): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ext/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(79): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('sales_email_ord...', 'sales', Array, Array, Array, '5')
 #5 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ext/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1393): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
 #6 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ext/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(276): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->sendOrderUpdateEmail('1', 'test')
 #7 /var/www/vhosts//domain.ext/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->addCommentAction()
 #8 /var/www/vhosts//domain.ext/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('addComment')
 #9 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ext/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
 #10 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ext/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
 #11 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ext/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /var/www/vhosts/domain.ext/httpdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
```

---

the qmail wrapper show the email header with no problems
no errors in mail.log

error.log reports:

```
 qmail-inject: fatal: unable to parse this line:
 From: Global-seller: e-commerce <senderemail>
```

*** (senderemail = right magento email) ***

the smtp on server is running fine (all other domains are sending e-mails)
Other magento installed on same server with different domain have no problems.
The magento setting are well configured as localhost on port 25

### postfix is not installed on the server

Any tips?
thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that it's because the from name is set to 'Global-net: e-commerce'. The extra colon might be throwing it off.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm guessing that it's because the from name is set to 'Global-seller: e-commerce'. The extra colon might be throwing it off. –  aynber 17 mins ago**

YES, SOLVED thanks –  user1847437 13 mins ago