# Magento CE 1.9.1.1 not sending sales emails

Tags: php, email, magento, cron

We are having issues with Magento not sending emails out. The emails having issues are the sales email which are logged into `core_email_queue`. None of these are sending. All other emails send fine through my server.

I am aware that `CE1.9.x` send emails through cron and my cron.php is running fine. `AOE scheduler` shows the cron is running. Only the emails are not being sent. In exception.log I see this issue which is exactly when the emails stopped going out and it repeats.

How can I fix this? It's a fresh install of `CE1.9.1.1` and I reinstalled just to be sure.

```
2015-04-30T01:35:03+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in /home/nli/catalog/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 /home/nli/catalog/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 /home/nli/catalog/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 /home/nli/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php(241): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue->send(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule))
#4 /home/nli/catalog/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(79): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /home/nli/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#6 /home/nli/catalog/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /home/nli/catalog/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#8 /home/nli/catalog/cron.php(76): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#9 {main}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think following post can help you.

[Magento:exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363623/magentoexception-zend-mail-transport-exception-with-message-unable-to-send-m)

There is a chance that your from address can have extra character that seems invalid.

Comment: Yes that was it. i just truncated the email queue tables and all is well now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can check this link out.

http://www.appseconnect.com/magento/magento-1-9-bug-sales-order-emails-does-not-hit-instantly-it-sends-when-magento-cron-jobs-is-initiated/

This will help you to get rid of late sending emails.

Comment: Can you add the most important things to your answer, Some users newer looks at links.